# Need text editor/composer like Wordpress

Tags: html, text-editor

I want a **Visual Text composer** like *Wordpress* or this(*stackoverflow*). i want to embed it on html page just like maps or facebook like box. I searched over Google but did not found any fruitful help, it gives me html editor. may be i missed some basic keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the words you should be looking for Visual Editor, WYSIWYG, TinyMCE . where u want to use it ?? any cms or just in html pages ??
[check this link for more info](http://mashable.com/2008/11/03/embeddable-html-editors/)

you will find all good editors with link to there website in above article

Answer (score 1):

If you have a WordPress site you can use a plugin called User Submitted Posts available here:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/
You can use Gravity Forms (http://www.gravityforms.com) to allow users to post.

You could also allow registered Wordpress users to write posts however that often complicates things.

If you are only using HTML you could possibly incorporate PHP and HTML5 forms to create posts.

I hope this helps.
Tom